# React avoid re render useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which uses `react-native-scrollable-tabview`. I'm having a problem though.

The component has 2 props: `page` and `initialPage`.

When rendering the component for the first time, I should set `initialPage`, otherwise it doesn't work.

However when rendering the component again, if I change this `initialPage` it goes the new page (tab) but it doesn't render it. BUT, if I set the `page` then it works.

So the idea is:

First render? Set `page` to undefined and `initialPage` to N.
Subsequent renders? Set `page` to N and `initialPage` to undefined.

I tried using a flag state variable like this:

```
const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);

let page = n;
let initialPage = n;

if(first){
   page = undefined;
   setFirstRender(false);
}else{
  initialPage = undefined;
}
```

Thing is, the `setFirstRender` triggers a re render so it doesn't work. However when I go to another screen (using react navigation) and I come back then it works fine.

Is there any way to update this `firstRender` without it triggering a re render?

Comment: Are `page` and `initialPage` props or variables inside the component? If they are props, why are you fiddling with their values?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe something with `useEffect` could help?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFirstRender(false);
}, []);
```

The array at the end is a dependency and tells the function to only run once, you could also add a value in there that runs only when that value changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you aren't checking the value of your state anywhere.

e.g this conditional:

```
if(first){
   page = undefined;
   setFirstRender(false);
}else{
  initialPage = undefined;
}
```

should be changed to rely on the value of state, which you declare as: 
`(const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);)`

so

```
if(firstRender){
   page = undefined;
   setFirstRender(false);
}else{
  initialPage = undefined;
}
```

Additionally, you will probably need to move this conditional into a useEffect where it will update only after the first initial page render.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (firstRender) {
setFirstRender(false) ...etc
```